# How to use VS Code C/C++ configurations properly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to VS Code and, coming from VS, I'm struggling to understand how to set up different configurations using the [Microsoft C/C++ extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). I followed the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp), but it seems to me that the content in `c_cpp_properties.json` is only affecting Intellisense and has no correlation to the actual build, which is set up in `tasks.json`. The configurations I enter are showing up and selectable at the lower right of the editor window: Intellisense reflects this by apparent knowledge about include folders, etc. However, when I build or run, they don't have any effect, I get errors such as "No such file or directory" for included files. As far as I see it, this is not mentioned in the documentation at all.

How can I make use of the actual selected configuration for the build system?

Comment: AFAIK you can't, the extension does not contain a build system and the properties are not linked to anything except the editor. You might have better luck using the CMake extension, which automatically adjusts the properties depending on the selected CMake configuration

Comment: The tasks compile the program and her you specify the possible include and lib directories. If your project has multiple cpp files use CMake of the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adriano-markovic.c-cpp-makefile-project

Comment: srsly? Then I don't get the point of having this functionality in the first place. This means, neither the cues in the editor nor the configuration selection in the status bar is reflecting what is actually being built, worse, it is even misleading? And I always have to make sure, manually, that the contents of task.json align with c_cpp_properties.json?